# Jquery & Canvas HTML5 in Conflict in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I have a problem , I'm a HTML/CSS web designer trying to learn more to integrate jQuery effects to a site. I spent an hour trying to find a solution to this conflict, the code is not working. It's a "matrix effect" jQuery script that uses HTML5 Canvas. The Library is being called before the script, but something seems to be wrong. Cant find out what.

The script I'm trying to use is in the second div after the introduction 1st div
is called

Inside this div I placed the canvas call ...

The source files are this ones:

http://www.arungudelli.com/html5/matrix-effect-using-html5-and-javascript/

On my site, the effect is not appearing :(

wordpress was adding stuff

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippet(s) here...

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  line 124`

Comment: its very specific to the theme-framework im using, if I post the code of the tutorial, or download html files, everything works properly, the problem is in the live version... on the link.

Comment: how can I fix it Howdy? there is nothjing in line 124 when I check rendered code

Comment: What is line 124 of your unrendered (raw) code?...

Comment: I searched with chrome but I cant see more than that information , Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < , !

Answer (score 0):

If we look at our console in Google Chrome we see there's an error on line 124, if we view our page source and scroll down to line 124 we see this bit of code:

```
var ctx=q.getContext('2d');</p>
<p>var draw = function () {
```

So for some reason or another there are some random paragraph tags being added to your javascript that are not encapsulated and it is throwing off your code. Remove that and continue debugging.